# How to condense a column like this?

Tags: mysql

I've tried finding something like this, but to no avail...

This is about a system of tables for a customer management system. In particular, I need to create a note history for each customer.

So, I have a table 'customers' with the columns `customers.customer_ID`, `customers.lastname`, `customers.firstname`, `customers.postal_code`, `customers.city` and `customers.street`;

and another table 'notes' with the columns `notes.note_ID`, `notes.customer_ID`, `notes.subject`, `notes.description` and `notes.entered_on`

Now I need to create a third table search which condenses much of the information above. It has the tables search.contact_ID, search.name, search.address and search.history. This is supposed to look like this:

```
contacts:
contact_ID  | lastname  | firstname | ...
------------+-----------+-----------+-----
1           | Doe       | John      | ...
2           | Dane      | Jane      | ...

note:
note_ID | contact_ID    | subject               | description           | entered_on
--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------
1       | 1             | call received         | John Doe called us to | 2014-05-03
        |               |                       | ask for an offer      |
2       | 1             | offer made            | We called John Doe to | 2014-06-03
        |               |                       | submit our offer      |
3       | 2             | advertisement call    | We called Jane Dane to| 2014-06-03
        |               |                       | inform her of our     |
        |               |                       | latest offer          |
4       | 1             | offer accepted        | John Doe called to    | 2014-08-03
        |               |                       | accept our offer      |

search:
contact_ID  |   name        |   address                       | history
------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------
1           | Doe, John     | 55 Main Street, 12345 Oldtown   | 'On 2014-08-03 offer accepted: John Doe accepted our offer.  
            |               |                                 | On 2014-06-03 offer made: We called John Doe to submit our offer. 
            |               |                                 | On 2014-05-03 call received: John Doe called us to ask for an offer.'
2           | Dane, Jane    | 111 Wall Street, 67890 Newtown  | 'On 2014-06-03 advertisement call: We called Jane Dane to submit our offer.'
```

While I can deal with much of the rest, I have no idea how to generate the history information. My idea was as follows

```
WHILE 
    customers.customer_ID = note.customer_ID 
    AND 
    note.entered_on = GREATEST(note.entered_on)
DO 
    SET customers.note_history = CONCAT_WS(' | ', CONCAT_WS(': ',note.subject,note.description), customers.note_history);
```

But that one isn't necessarily chronological. Also how do I transform that into a statement compatible with the `SELECT INTO` used for the creation of the rest of the table?

Comment: sound like you want to do something in MySQL that should be done in your application itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a case for a Group-By, along with `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
CREATE TABLE search (PRIMARY KEY(contact_ID))
  SELECT contact_ID, CONCAT(lastname,', ',firstname) AS name, address, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('On ',entered_on,' ',subject,': ',description) 
        ORDER BY note_ID SEPARATOR "\n") AS history
  FROM contacts LEFT JOIN note USING (contact_ID)
  GROUP BY contact_ID
```

If dont want to use `CREATE TABLE .. SELECT ...` , can first just create (or truncate!) the table, and then use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` instead.

Comment: on closer inspection, see you dont have an address column, it would need to be composed. But the example for name, shows using the CONCAT function to do it.

Comment: Thank you, that one worked when using `ORDER BY entered_on` to make sure I have chronological order for the grouping.